# Migrate standard DAO with SQL to Hibernate and/or Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on project, that uses Spring framework (Spring MVC, DAO etc.)
Project is not so big and uses Jetty servlet container, PostgreSQL database with standard DAO classes(sql requests). I need to make it possible to use Hibernate/Spring JPA instead SQL queries.
I found a few states describes migration to spring boot:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration
https://3ldn.nl/2016/02/16/spring-boot-in-an-existing-application-part-1/
I'm add spring boot dependencies in project:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
```

Also I add package "entity" on the same level with old UserDao class and I need to use Spring JPA Repositories instead of using old DAO classes.
What actions I need to do for that replacement for table Users, that contains user id, name and email?
Need I use Hibernate or Spring JPA is enough?

Comment: Very hard to answer your question, because migrating need many steps.

Comment: please reopen question, I don't want create the same topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to migrate to Spring Boot if you don't want to. Spring Boot has much easier configuration than legacy spring project, but still you can use legacy.

If you want to use Repositories as your data access layer, you can use Spring Data JPA with Postgres Driver [Spring Data JPA Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), but if you want to use only Hibernate with standard DAO classes, and EntityManager, you can add only hibernate dependency, Spring ORM and Postgres Driver. After that you just need to configure your Persistence Unit and Transaction managment withis your application (through persistence.xml or Java configuration).

Comment: Thx, I m concrete my question with more details. Moderators, please reopen my question - its not solved and now it contains all needed information.